# Replacing / Unifying Attributes

Tags: attributes, products-management, attribute-set

I'm not a programmer and I am in charge with a Magento online store developed a year ago by someone else.

I have to solve a problem and need to know if it can be done without programming (in order to solve it fast) or I must wait until hire a Magento programmer.

Problem: 
The store has several categories (fragrances, cosmetics, drinks, tobacco, accessories, sweets and toys).

Products in each categories has separate attribute sets.
For each attribute set, there is a `brand` attribute (for example, in fragrances's attribute set I have `brand`, in drinks's attribute set I have `drink_brand` and so on).

I want to unify all brands (frangrance, drinks, accessories, toys, a.s.o) under only one attribute named `brand`.

Can I add to the existing `brand` attribute (which, by the way, contains only the fragrance brands) all other brands (for drinks, accessories, toys...) an then replace this attribute in all attribute sets?

Comment: Hi Cosminium, You dont worry to add one attribute in many attribute sets. You can feel free to add attribute in attribute sets without program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible and if you have good reasons for it, do it. A good reason would be having a single brand attribute in the filter navigation if you search across multiple categories.

Just be aware that the result will be one attribute with lots of options. Magento does not handle thousands of options per attribute well, this can be a performance problem in some areas.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the reason.. To have only one filtrable attribute in navigation column. Right now, I have at least 2 "Brand" attributes any time and this is creating a lot of confusion among customers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can add your attribute in various attribute set from admin.

Go to

```
Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute Sets
```

Click on attribute set and move your brand attribute to your attribute set group where you want. Same way you can remove any attribute from your attribute set.

Comment: I know that but I want to find out if can have problems later (store crashes or misbehavior) or updates (stocks, prices).

Comment: adding attribute to attribute set or removing it from any attribute set will not cause any issue. but you will need to make sure you do not have any custom coding based on the attribute set for particular attribute also make sure you do not have any  catalog or shopping cart price rules available for particular attribute which you want to remove from attribute sets.

Comment: Thank a lot for help